# Creating a lambda function to store metadata of file in S3 to the Mysql database?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and I am currently trying to understand Lambda functions and to trigger it when I upload file to S3 bucket. 
I wrote a handler class for this:

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Employee, String> {
    public String handleRequest(Employee input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("helloWorld");
        return "Hello World " ;
    }
}
```

This was just a basic and I could see the "helloworld" printed in logs in CloudWatch when I upload a file to S3 bucket.

But Now what I want to log the metadata of the file (fileName, createdTime etc.).

I went thru a sample template example in AWS Lambda page, where I can see using Nodejs,  we have the `event` as the argument and we can extract the name and other fields using this field.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    ...

}
```

But as a Java developer, I tried to use `S3EventNotification` as the argument:

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<S3EventNotification, String> {
    public String handleRequest(S3EventNotification input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log(input.getRecords().get(0).getEventSource());
        return "Hello World " ;
    }
}
```

But I am getting below error:

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: lambdainternal.util.ReflectUtil$ReflectException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3ObjectEntity.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3ObjectEntity.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Java? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some variant of the following:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event;

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Void> {
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
        try {
            S3EventNotificationRecord record = s3event.getRecords().get(0);

            String bkt = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
            String key = record.getS3().getObject().getKey().replace('+', ' ');
            key = URLDecoder.decode(key, "UTF-8");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // do something
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

And here are the corresponding dependencies that I used in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.228</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the build specification from my pom.xml (which will cause dependent classes to be pulled into my built JAR):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

None of this is very simple, unfortunately, but that's Java and Maven for you. AWS Lambda programming in Node.js or Python is much simpler (and more fun) than in Java, so if there's no strong requirement to write it in Java, you're better off *not* writing in Java.

Also note that if the Lambda is going to be invoked asynchronously then the output type should be Void rather than String (see [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html)).

Comment: There is no method as getRecords() in S3Event class

Comment: You're using the wrong S3Event. Easily done as there are 2 of them. I've added the imports to the code.

Comment: Thanks for replying soon. I couldn't get the S3 event class from lambda package. Could you tell me the dependency in pom.xml for that S3Event class?

Comment: Believe it's aws-lambda-java-events (and possibly aws-lambda-java-core).

Comment: I added that dependency but still getting error. Same error as in this link :https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/2

Comment: I have created  a trigger to activate this when I am uploading a object to S3. Please help me in solving this

Comment: Could you please tell me what is wrong I am doing https://ufile.io/v6w15

Comment: Seems like version no of AWS api makes a huge difference.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have got it working. Good luck with the remainder of the project.

Comment: If I have to sendMessage to sqs , Is the QUEUE URL enought to send a message?

Comment: See example here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs-messages.html, but yes. You'll also need credentials, of course.

Comment: Once we process the message successfully, do we have to delete it on our own? Also I am processing it in lambda, thats why may be I don't have to give the credentials.

Comment: The documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) is the best place to investigate these type of questions. It will also give you the big picture which is important context to help you succeed.